# input type number - form.$error does not work with Chrome and IE but fine with FF

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have input type number whose `min` and `max` values defined.
It works fine on Firefox and shows error message if i enter value other than number `e.g. abc or 11 or -1` but it does give the same output when try on chrome and IE.

Whats wrong here?

```
<div>
    <label>Size</label>
    <div >
        <div>
            <input type="number" name="maxSize" data-ng-model="Size" min="0" max="10"/>
        </div>
        <div data-ng-if="Form.maxSize.$error.number">Please enter a number between 0 and 10</div>
        <div data-ng-if="Form.maxSize.$error.min">Please enter a number between 0 and 10</div>
        <div data-ng-if="Form.maxSize.$error.max" >Please enter a number between 0 and 10</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you enlocsing them in <form> tag ?

Comment: yes they are inside form tag

Answer (score 1):

Open this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_number) in Firefox and IE.

`Input Type Number` is `HTML5` element. All browsers are not yet fully supporting HTML5. So `Input Type Number` will fallback to `Input Type Text`. So your default HTML5 validation will not work. you have write JS to handle this.

Note: I don't know Angular but this is just HTML5 observation